# Delete All Subscriber and Upload Lists again

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

everybody,

in the last weeks we have defined addresses from the All Subscriber List that we want to keep and a number of 400k that we would delete.

The users we want to keep are divided into 4 different data extensions. Actually, the plan was to delete the All Subscribers and then upload the Data Extensions again and add the All Subscribers accordingly.

Is that possible? Or what would be the best course of action?

Thx

Comment: I would never recommend this - unless your DBOR is outside of SFMC and even then, it is highly specialized use-case. You delete all subscription status and related history when removed from All subscribers. This can leave you open to CAN-SPAM violations if you add a previously unsub email after deleting it as it will now be displayed as active, not unsubbed.

Answer (score 3):

Although not recommended, you can delete subscribers from the all subscribers list.
As opposed to doing in the the way you have highlighted, I would advice the following:

- Import the subscribers you wish to delete into a list.
- Delete the list
- Select the option to also delete them from the all subscribers list.

> **Note:**
>
> If you have an enterprise 2.0 account, you must do this at the parent
>   account level, otherwise this will not work.

See also: [Bulk Delete from All Subscribers List](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153631/bulk-delete-from-all-subscribers-list/158116#158116)